# Understanding parameters in Postgres Like command in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

**How can you use parameters in Postgres `Like` command?**

I am reading [this document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/functions-matching.html).
I am trying to search a word `lorem` in the table `questions` and in its column `body`.

I run unsuccessfully the following code inside PHP

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn, 
    "SELECT question_id, body
    FROM questions
    WHERE body ilike '%$1%'",
    array ( $_GET['search'])                                                                                                                                                       
);
```

I get this warning

> Warning: pg_query_params() [function.pg-query-params]: Query
>   failed: ERROR: bind message supplies 1
>   parameters, but prepared statement ""
>   requires 0 in
>   /var/www/codes/search_body.php on line
>   10
>       Call Stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a parameter in place of one *whole* value, and not inside quotes.

Solution 1: concatenate the `LIKE` wildcards into the parameter value:

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn, 
    "SELECT question_id, body
    FROM questions
    WHERE body ilike $1",
    array ( "%" . $_GET['search'] . "%")
);
```

Solution 2: concatenate the `LIKE` wildcards in the SQL expression:

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn, 
    "SELECT question_id, body
    FROM questions
    WHERE body ilike '%' || $1 || '%'",
    array ( $_GET['search'] )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think because the $1 is in single quotes it is taken as literal, instead of a placeholder.

Try:

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn, 
    "SELECT question_id, body
    FROM questions
    WHERE body ilike $1",
    array ('%' . $_GET['search'] . '%')                                                                                                                                                       
);
```